# How to login with login token in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services

In my application i have to login with login token and some parameter are as below and i got response for login token as"45462165" in NSLog but can't go to another view controller.

```
Method: PMac_LogIn  
Parameter: mailaddress String with @   
password String     
Return: If ok, then you receive a loginToken. (> 0)   
If not ok, then loginToken < 0   
-1 = user not found  
-2 = wrong password   
When you can not reach the server, you have to inform the user in dialog, with “Server not available”. In the cases -1 or -2 you should inform the user.
```

and here is my code :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //your prompt -> token fail
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"-1"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"-2"] ) {


        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"User Not Exist" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
        [errorAlert release];

    }



       NSInteger LenghtloginToken = [elementName length];
    if(LenghtloginToken >=0 ) {
        //success

        UploadViewController *hm;

        hm = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:hm animated:YES];



    }

}
```

Comment: do you need  LenghtloginToken in another viewcontroller

Comment: yes i need it and i have got 4 time lenghtlogintoken now in nslog

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods for sharing data you can follow one of them according to your requirements

1.You can always share data using NSUserDefaults. Set the value you want to share with respect to a key of your choice and get the value from NSUserDefault associated to that key in the next view controller.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: LenghtloginToken forKey:@"LenghtloginToken"]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LenghtloginToken"]
```

2.You can just create a property in viewcontrollerA. Create an object of viewcontrollerA in viewcontrollerB and assign the desired value to that property.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSInteger passedNumber;
```

Add
`@synthesize  passedNumber; in` `UploadViewController`

And last

```
UploadViewController *hm = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViewController" bundle:nil];

hm.passedNumber = LenghtloginToken;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:hm animated:YES];
```

3.You can also create custom delegates for this.

You can check this [link](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) for passing data using custom delegate

Comment: but i have got login parameters as if logintoken >=0 then i user should login

Comment: where is second approach did u mention?

Comment: i have to do this by web service and got token by server look at my code please and give appropriate answer

Comment: if([LenghtloginToken intValue] > 0 ) compare like this

Comment: it also not happening right becoz my token name is iLoginToken and also i tried it many time

Comment: can you tell me the type of your token (int, NSInteger)

Comment: int i think but not suere

Comment: its int value because

Comment: token is used in android application also so

Comment: 100% this is int value

Comment: your comparison seems right please replace [self.navigationController pushViewController:hm animated:YES]; with  [self presentModalViewController:admin animated:YES];